# how to extract pandas series element and compare it with rows in dataframe's column

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a following dataframe..

```
     coupon_type     dish_id  dish_name   dish_price  dish_quantity
0     Rs 20 off       012      Sandwich     65            2
1     Rs 20 off       013       Chicken     125           3
2     Rs 20 off       013       Chicken     125           3
3     Rs 20 off       013       Chicken     125           3

    ratings    reviews      coupon_type  user_id order_id  meals order_area
    4     blah blah blah   Rs 20 off      9       9         5     London
    4     blah blah blah   Rs 20 off      9       9         5     London
    3     blah blah blah   Rs 20 off      9       9         5     London
    4     blah blah blah   Rs 20 off      9       9         5     London
```

I am doing groupby on dish_name column.

```
df_dish_name = df_final.groupby('dish_name')
```

Then I am performing some ratio operations on groupby.

Which gives me following pandas series..which I am storing in dish_specific_perf

```
dish_name
Chicken       45.000000
Sandwich      61.111111
```

Then I am checking one condition in if loop..

```
if((dish_specific_perf < 50).any() == True):
```

If the condition is true then, I want to add ("NP") string to corresponding dish name in dataframe.. So, In dataframe it should look like this.

```
 coupon_type     dish_id  dish_name   dish_price  dish_quantity
0     Rs 20 off       012      Sandwich     65            2
1     Rs 20 off       013       Chicken     125           3
2     Rs 20 off       013       Chicken     125           3
3     Rs 20 off       013       Chicken     125           3

    ratings    reviews      coupon_type  user_id order_id  meals order_area
    4     blah blah blah   Rs 20 off      9       9         5     London
    4     blah blah blah   Rs 20 off      9       9         5     London
    3     blah blah blah   Rs 20 off      9       9         5     London
    4     blah blah blah   Rs 20 off      9       9         5     London  

  Flag
  Null
  NP
  NP
  NP
```

The problem with this is how do I compare series elements with dataframe dish_name column to check whether chicken exist or not?

when I do

```
dish_specific_perf[0]
```

It just gives me a number as 45.

Please help..

Comment: IIUC then you can do `df_final['Flag'] = df_final['dish_name'].map(dish_specific_perf < 50)` this will set the flag to `True` or `False` you can then set these to NP/Null as desired `df_final['Flag'] = np.where(df_final['Flag'], 'NP', 'Null')`

Comment: @EdChum Exactly what I am looking for.. Thanks alot..;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially you are looking to do a lookup for that we can use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html#pandas.Series.map) on the boolean series so the following will add a boolean flag:

```
df_final['Flag'] = df_final['dish_name'].map(dish_specific_perf < 50)
```

This works by looking up the df value against the series index and returning the value.

You can then convert the boolean values to your desired flag:

```
df_final['Flag'] = np.where(df_final['Flag'], 'NP', 'Null')
```

Comment: can we have two conditions in map? ` df_final['dish_name'].map(dish_specific_perf > 50 & dish_specific < 70)`

Comment: yes that'll work but you need to wrap parentheses around the conditions due to operator precedence: `df_final['dish_name'].map((dish_specific_perf > 50) & (dish_specific < 70))`

Comment: I am trying with 2 different series conditions but its not giving me results.. `df_final['dish_name'].map((dish_relative_perf < 10) & (dish_specific_perf < 50))`   `dish_relative_perf is one series and dish_specific_perf is another series.` It just executes first condition not both.

Comment: Unless the 2 series have matching indices then that won't work

Comment: You'll need to post a new question with your input data, code to reproduce your dfs, and your desired output

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` statement is wrong for your needs, to begin with. I would do the whole thing in the loop over groups like so:

```
for name, group in df_dish_name:
    # Whatever awesome thing you are doing, which give you the ratio...

    if ratio < 50:
        df_final.loc[df_final['dish_name']==name, 'Flag'] = 'NP'
```

This will avoid indexing and selecting multiple times, and is easier to maintain.

Comment: Its setting all the corresponding rows to be NP.. I want only those rows to be set NP which are true for if condition..

Comment: From your question I guessed you do want to set all rows where the group aggregate ratio is less than 50.